# Insert TextBox value into first empty cell in column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which works fine. (TextBoxes are on "UserForm" in Excel VBA, and executes with clicking CommandButton1 on that UserForm.) But can anyone help me to insert the value of each TextBox into the first empty cell in Column M? This way inserts empty rows. I will use this in several workbooks, so using "ActiveSheet" is easiest for me.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.TextBox1.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value)
Me.TextBox2.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M2").Value)
Me.TextBox3.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M3").Value)
Me.TextBox4.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M4").Value)
Me.TextBox5.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M5").Value)
Me.TextBox6.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M6").Value)
Me.TextBox7.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M7").Value)
Me.TextBox8.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M8").Value)
Me.TextBox9.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M9").Value)
Me.TextBox10.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M10").Value)
Me.TextBox11.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M11").Value)
Me.TextBox12.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M12").Value)
Me.TextBox13.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M13").Value)
Me.TextBox14.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M14").Value)
Me.TextBox15.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M15").Value)
Me.TextBox16.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M16").Value)
Me.TextBox17.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M17").Value)
Me.TextBox18.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M18").Value)
Me.TextBox19.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M19").Value)
Me.TextBox20.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M20").Value)
Me.TextBox21.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M21").Value)
Me.TextBox22.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M22").Value)
End Sub

'Insert Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("M1") = Me.TextBox1.Text
Range("M2") = Me.TextBox2.Text
Range("M3") = Me.TextBox3.Text
Range("M4") = Me.TextBox4.Text
Range("M5") = Me.TextBox5.Text
Range("M6") = Me.TextBox6.Text
Range("M7") = Me.TextBox7.Text
Range("M8") = Me.TextBox8.Text
Range("M9") = Me.TextBox9.Text
Range("M10") = Me.TextBox10.Text
Range("M11") = Me.TextBox11.Text
Range("M12") = Me.TextBox12.Text
Range("M13") = Me.TextBox13.Text
Range("M14") = Me.TextBox14.Text
Range("M15") = Me.TextBox15.Text
Range("M16") = Me.TextBox16.Text
Range("M17") = Me.TextBox17.Text
Range("M18") = Me.TextBox18.Text
Range("M19") = Me.TextBox19.Text
Range("M20") = Me.TextBox20.Text
Range("M21") = Me.TextBox21.Text
Range("M22") = Me.TextBox22.Text
Range("A25").Value = "Hide"
Unload Me
End Sub

Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'Cancel button
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Inserting "Hide" into "A25" hides Row M.

Comment: "Row M"? `M` is a column, not a row.

Comment: My bad. I'm so frustrated after spending hours trying to get this done. Insert the value into the first empty cell in the COLUMN M and then "Hide" hides COLUMNS M:Q

Comment: First empty cell or last empty cell of `Column M`? `Hide` hides means what? Do you want to hide any row?

Comment: So based on what you posted, "the first empty cell in column M" would be `M23`, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Or are you trying to trigger code when the user enters the word "hide" into cell A25 that does something? Your question is not very clear at all.

Comment: You can ignore the "Hide" command. It triggers something in a different code - hiding columns M:Q. I have 22 cells in Row M: M1:M2. The user will send the code to up to 22 people whose email address are in the TextBoxes 1-22. I want to enter the TextBox value into a corresponding cell, but I don't want there to be any blank cells, except at the bottom of the column of cells with data in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: last guess

You can do something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long, c As Range
    ActiveSheet.Range("M1:M22").ClearContents
    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("M1")

    For i = 1 to 22
        c.Value = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Text
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 then Set c = c.offset(1, 0)      
    Next i

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: When my UserForm loads, it puts the email address that are already in the cells into the text boxes using Me.TextBox1.Value = CStr(ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value). @Tim Williams, your code works, but it adds what is already in the boxes to the end, so the cells have duplicate values.

Comment: Your update code does the same thing: It pastes duplicate values at the end of what is already there...

Comment: Have you considered clearing the range M1:M22 before re-populating it?  That seems to be the way to go...

Comment: That actually sounds like a great way to fix it.  Any thoughts on how to do that and where in the code to put it?

Comment: `Range("M1:M22").ClearContents` as the first line in commandbutton1_click